# Data Variables/Constants and Type int Constants (C Primer Plus)

Tags: c, variables, int, constants, literals

world. I'm a novice in CS field and learning C language with a book called 'C Primer Plus'.
I have a question regarding C data types (Chapter 3 of the book).

In the book, it is written that

> #### Data Variable and Constants
>
> [...] Some types of data are preset before a program is used and keep their values unchanged throughout the life of the programs. These are *constants*. Other types of data may change or be assigned values as the program runs; these are *variables*. In the sample program, weight is a variable and 14.5833 is a constant. [...] The difference between a variable and a constant is that a variable can have its value assigned or changed while the program is running, and a constant can't.

the below is the sample program.

```
/* platinum.c -- your weight in platinum */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float weight;
    float value;

    printf("Are you worth your weight in platinum?\n");
    printf("Let's check it out.\n);
    printf("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");

    scanf("%f", &weight);
    value = 1700.0 * weight * 14.5833;
    printf("Your weight in platinum is worth $%.2f.\n", value);
    printf("You are easily worth that! If platinum prices drop,\n");
    printf("eat more to maintain your value.\n);

    return 0;
}
```

and the next,

> #### Data: Data-type Keywords
>
> Beyond the distinction between variable and constant is the distinction between different *types* of data. [...] If a datum is a constant, the compiler can usually tell its type just by the way it looks. [...] A variable , however, needs to have its type announced in a declaration statement. [...]

Everything made sense to me until I read this below.

> #### Initializing a Variable
>
> To *initilize* a variable means to assign it a starting, or *initial*, value. [...] Here are some examples:

```
int hogs = 21;
int cows = 32, goats = 14
int dogs, cats = 94;        /* valid, but poor, form */
```

and the following is,

> #### Type int Constants
>
> The various integers (21, 32, 14 and 94) in the last example are *integer constants*, also called *integer literals*.

It confuses me because how I understood is that constants and variables are different. And one of the differences is to be declared w/ its type or not to. but the value of the initialized variable in declare statements are called integer constants.
Now my questions are 
1.why is there a difference between data constant and integer constant/literal?
2.How are they different?
3.What am I missing in this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Well, If you have `21` in your code (it is an integer literal), you can't put it on the left-side of the equal sign. For example `21 = 32;` makes no sense. A constant is the same way, e.g. `const int foo = 21;` you can't then do `foo = 32;`. Now the important point to note is that `foo` is not an integer literal, but it cannot be modified. To provide a named integer literal, you must `#define FOO 21`. The importance is `foo` isn't known until runtime while `FOO` is known at compile-time. This makes a difference if you try `int arr[foo];` and `int arr[FOO];`

Comment: The *"What am I missing in this?"* is the *"Why it matters?"* part. You are not missing anything conceptually (you may be overthinking it a bit). But the *"Why it matters?"* part boils down to what is known at compile time, and what is known at run-time. A defined constant, e.g. `#define FOO 21` makes `FOO` known at compile time. It can be used as a valid literal to define arrays, e.g. `int arr[FOO];`, etc.. While simply `const int foo = 21;` is something not known until runtime and even though declared `const` is not a literal. `int arr[foo];` results in a *Variable Length Array* instead.

Comment: You're right. I was overthinking it. Thank you.

Comment: Happens to us all -- but you are asking the right questions `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is there a difference between data constant and integer constant/literal?

There isn't.  An integer constant is a *type* of data constant.  Those declaration statements are *initializing* the variables with the values of the constants - given

```
int hogs = 21;
```

the *variable* `hogs` will contain the value `21` - we've copied the value of the constant into the variable.

Here are some more examples:

```
double     d = 1.234; // copy the value 1.234 into d 
char       c = 'a';   // copy the character value 'a' into c
char   str[] = "foo"; // copy the contents of the string "foo" into the array str - size of the array is taken from the size of the initializer.
```

Integer, floating point, and string constants can have suffixes that tell the compiler to use a specific type instead of assuming `int` or `double` or whatever.  `1234U` means "treat `1234` as an *unsigned* integer", `3.1415f` means "treat `3.1415` as a `float`, not a `double`", etc.  You probably don't need to worry about that quite yet, though.

**So, why does type *matter*?**

Different types have different *representations* in memory - the bit pattern for the integer value `1234` looks *nothing* like the bit pattern for the floating point value `1234.0`, which looks nothing like the bit pattern for the *string* `"1234"`.  If we try to store a string value in an integer variable and try to use it as an integer, our program would not behave as expected.  So the compiler has rules that prevent us from assigning values of *incompatible* types to variables.

Let's go back to our variable initialization:

```
int hog = 21;
```

We're telling the compiler that the variable `hog` has type `int`, and we're *initializing* it with a constant expression.  For the compiler to accept this, the constant expression *also* needs to have type `int` (or a type *compatible* with `int`).  If we write

```
int hog = "21";
```

the compiler will complain that we're attempting to initialize `hog` with a value of the wrong type.